# What characters are allowed in twitter hashtags?

Tags: twitter, hashtag

In developing an iOS app containing a twitter client, I must allow for user generated hashtags (which may be created elsewhere within the app, not just in the tweet body).

I would like to ensure any such hashtags are valid for twitter, so I would like to error check the entered value for invalid characters. Bear in mind that users may be from non-English speaking countries.

I am aware of the usual limitations, such as not beginning a hashtag with a number, and no special punctuation characters, but I was wondering if there is a known list of all additional characters that are technically allowed within hashtags (i.e. international characters).

Comment: I can confirm for cyrillic you may easely find a lot of tweets in russian like this one https://twitter.com/search?q=%23%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82&src=typd

Comment: Please don't forget to accept one of the answers. It will help everyone who comes across this page in the future (How to accept answers: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/2068165)

Answer (score 10):

Karl, as you've rightly pointed out, any word in any language can be a valid twitter hashtag (as long as it meets a number of basic criteria). As such what you are asking for is a list of valid international word characters. I'm sure someone has compiled such a list somewhere, but using it would not be the most efficient approach to reaching what appears to be your initial goal: ensuring that a given hashtag is valid for twitter.

I believe, what you are looking for is a regular expression that can match all word characters *within a Unicode range*. Such an expression would not be dependant on your locale and would match all characters in the modern typography that can appear as part of a word.

You didn't specify what language you are writing your app in, so I can't help you with a language specific implementation. However, the basic approach would be as follows:

1. Check if any of the bracket expressions or character classes already support *Unicode character ranges* in your language. If yes, then use them.
2. Check if there is regex modifier that can enable *Unicode character range* support for your language.

Most modern languages implement regular expressions in a fairly similar way and a lot of them borrow heavily from Perl, so I hope the following two example will put you on the right track:

**Perl:**

Use POSIX bracket expressions (eg: `[[:alpha:]]`, `[[:allnum:]]`, `[[:digit:]]`, etc) as they give you greater control over the characters you want to match, compared to character classes (eg: `\w`).

Use `/u` modifier to enable Unicode support when pattern matching. Under this modifier, the ASCII platform effectively becomes a Unicode platform; and hence, for example, `\w` will match any of the more than 100,000 word characters in Unicode.

See Perl documentation for more info:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Character-set-modifiers
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#POSIX-Character-Classes

**Ruby:**

Use POSIX bracket expressions as they encompass non-ASCII characters. For instance, /\d/ matches only the ASCII decimal digits (0-9); whereas /[[:digit:]]/ matches any character in the Unicode Nd category.

See Ruby documentation for more info:

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes

**Examples:**

Given a list of hashtags, the following regex will match all hashtags that start with a word character (inc. international word characters) followed by at least one other word character, a number or an underscore:

```
    m/^#[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]+$/u     # Perl

    /^#[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]+$/       # Ruby
```

Answer (score 6):

Twitter allows letters, numbers, and underscores.

I checked this by generating tweets via their API. For example, tweeting

> Hash tag test #foo[bar

resulted in "#foo" being marked as a hash tag, and "[bar" being unformatted text.

Comment: Can you clarify which letters? Not sure if you read my question in its entirety, but I would like to know what international characters are supported, if any.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add that in addition to alphanumeric characters and underscore, you can apparently use em dash in a Twitter hashtag like `#COVIDー19`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters you can't use a # in the hashtag (##hash).

The guidelines below are being quoted from [Twitter's help center](https://support.twitter.com/articles/49309-what-are-hashtags-symbols):

> - People use the hashtag symbol # before a relevant keyword or phrase (no spaces) in their Tweet to categorize those Tweets and help them show more easily in Twitter Search.
> - Clicking on a hashtagged word in any message shows you all other Tweets marked with that keyword.
> - Hashtags can occur anywhere in the Tweet – at the beginning, middle, or end.
> - Hashtagged words that become very popular are often Trending Topics.
>     Example: In the Tweet below, @eddie included the hashtag #FF. Users created this as shorthand for "Follow Friday," a weekly tradition where users recommend people that others should follow on Twitter. You'll see this on Fridays.
>
> **Using hashtags correctly:**
>
> - If you Tweet with a hashtag on a public account, anyone who does a search for that hashtag may find your Tweet
> - Don't #spam #with #hashtags. Don't over-tag a single Tweet. (Best practices recommend using no more than 2 hashtags per Tweet.)
> - Use hashtags only on Tweets relevant to the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I'm aware of the guidelines. I just can't seem to find a definitive list of what foreign characters are allowed in hashtags. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

Only letters and numbers are allowed to be part of a hashtag. If a character other than these follows the leading `#` and a letter or number, the hashtag will be cut off at this point.

I would recommend that your user interface indicate this to the user by changing the text color of the input field if the user enters anything other than a letter or number.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue to implement in golang.
It seems allowed chars with [[:alpha:]] is only English-alphabet and could not use this syntax for other language characters.
Instead, I could use \p{L} for this purpose.

My test with \p{L} is [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ULKWfGXZb-7).
* Arabic, Hebrew, Hindi...etc is not confirmed yet.