# unlist keeping the same number of elements (vectorized)

Tags: r, twitter, vectorization, stringr

I am trying to extract all hashtags from some tweets, and obtain for each tweet a single string with all hashtags.
I am using `str_extract` from `stringr`, so I obtain a list of character vectors. My problem is that I do not manage to unlist it and keep the same number of elements of the list (that is, the number of tweets).
Example:

This is a vector of tweets of length 3:

```
a <- "rt @ugh_toulouse: #mondial2014 : le top 5 des mannequins brésiliens http://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2014/06/01/1892121-mondial-2014-le-top-5-des-mannequins-bresiliens.html #brésil "
b <- "rt @30millionsdamis: beauté de la nature : 1 #baleine sauve un naufragé ; elles pourtant tellement menacées par l'homme... http://goo.gl/xqrqhd #instinctanimal "
c <- "rt @onlyshe31: elle siège toujours!!!!!!!  marseille. nouveau procès pour la députée - 01/06/2014 - ladépêche.fr http://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2014/06/01/1892035-marseille-nouveau-proces-pour-la-deputee.html #toulouse "
all <- c(a, b, c)
```

Now I use `str_extract_all` to extract the hashtags:

```
ex <- str_extract_all(all, "#(.+?)[ |\n]")
```

If I now use `unlist` I get a vector of length 5:

```
undesired <- unlist(ex)
> undesired
[1] "#mondial2014 "    "#brésil "        
[3] "#baleine "        "#instinctanimal "
[5] "#toulouse "
```

What I want is something like the following. However this is *very* inefficient, because it is not vectorized, and it takes forever (really!) on a smallish data frame of tweets:

```
desired <- c()
for (i in 1:length(ex)){
  desired[i] <- paste(ex[[i]], collapse = " ")
}

> desired
[1] "#mondial2014  #brésil "    
[2] "#baleine  #instinctanimal "
[3] "#toulouse "
```

Help!

Comment: Your regex is inefficient and a bit wrong.  (You shouldn't have a `+` modifier *and* a `?` modifier, and matching against `.` is slow.)  Try `"#([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*)"`. (But double check if this works with unicode characters in your locale.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/14823376/134830)

Comment: Great advice. I ended up using this on my data `data$hashtags <- str_trim(str_replace_all(sapply(stri_extract_all_regex(data$texte_du_tweet, '#([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*)'), paste, collapse=' '), "[^[:alnum:] ]", ""))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `stringi` which may be faster for big datasets

```
library(stringi)
sapply(stri_extract_all_regex(all, '#(.+?)[ |\n]'), paste, collapse=' ')
#[1] "#mondial2014  #brésil "     "#baleine  #instinctanimal "
#[3] "#toulouse "
```

The `for` loops can be fast if you `preassign` the length of the output `desired`

```
desired <- numeric(length(ex))
for (i in 1:length(ex)){
  desired[i] <- paste(ex[[i]], collapse = " ") 
}
```

Or you could use `vapply` which would be faster than `sapply` and a bit safer (contributed by @Richie Cotton)

```
vapply(ex, toString, character(1))
#[1] "#mondial2014 , #brésil "     "#baleine , #instinctanimal "
#[3] "#toulouse "
```

Or as suggested by @Ananda Mahto

```
 vapply(stri_extract_all_regex(all, '#(.+?)[ |\n]'),
              stri_flatten, character(1L), collapse = " ")
```

Comment: I'd be tempted by `desired <- vapply(ex, toString, character(1))` for the last part.

Comment: `sapply(stri_extract_all_regex(all, '#(.+?)[ |\n]'), paste, collapse=' ')` works as a charm. Thank you both a lot.

Comment: @akrun, why not stringi all the things? `vapply(stri_extract_all_regex(all, '#(.+?)[ |\n]'), stri_flatten, character(1L), collapse = " ")`? :-)